# Excel - Compare more than a column using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, duplicates

I need to compare my list of latitude/longitude (columns 4 and 5) with a database containing latitude/longitude data (columns 1 and 2) and its associated data (column 3). This associated data I need to ascribe to the relevant latitude and longitude in column 6. There are no duplicates in the database.

I have tried to use the index functionality etc but have had little luck.

```
DatabaseLat DatabaseLon Data        Lat      Lon    CopiedData
31.2    -87.9   5                   30.5    -87.1   3
31.9    -88.3   6                   31.9    -88.4   10
31.9    -88.4   10                  54      -87.1
31.1    -87.2   2                   31.2    -87.9   5
30.5    -87.1   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was something close to what you were looking forward to, by just using formula than a macro/script.

Essentially done using a concatenate function and VLOOKUP.

Step 1. concatenate value from your database and add it under Col A.

Step 2. Use VLOOKUP as in the image and compare using the concatenated value.
`=VLOOKUP(CONACTENATE(H2,I2), $A$2:$D$10,4, 0)`

Note: the syntax is using LibreOffice the function name may slightly differ.

[image: Image containing your data with formula]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will have to:

1. Write a VBA Excell macro script [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4W5LeeC4Z8)
2. Make use of `for each` loop, to go through every cell of column 4 and compare it to the same row of column 1.
3. If they hold the same value you just check column 2 and 5 simply by adding 1 to the current column number, which will move you to the right. eg.
   if cell E5 == A1 then [E +1 = F ] if cell F5 == B1, you have a match. So you can extract from C1 the  Database number.

Or, take a look at this methods [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Data-in-Excel)

I can't help more, I don't work on windows sorry, and good luck.

Comment: I think there is an excel function to do this without having to write a script.

Comment: Please check the second link in the answer.